# Unlock bitlocker drive from java via cmd

Tags: java, windows, command-line

I am trying to unlock a drive secured by bitlocker from Java. As far as I know there are no libs which can help me to handle that, so I was trying it through cmd. Here's the code:

```
    public static boolean unlockDisk(String pwd) throws IOException
{
    String[] script =
    {
            "manage-bde.exe", "-unlock", "D:", "-password",
    };

    Process process = new ProcessBuilder(script).start();
    InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
    final OutputStream outputStream = process.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
    writer.write(pwd);
    writer.newLine();
    writer.close();
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Bitlocker log:");
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    bufferedReader.close();

    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
    System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
    String tmp;
    while ((tmp = stdError.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(tmp);
    }
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------");

    return true;
}
```

**My Problem**

If I execute this java code I get `The handle is invalid` with `Code 0x80070006`.

**What I already tried**

1. Different JDK Version 32 and 64 Bit Java 8 and Java 7 (JDK 32 complains somehow that it can't find the command `manage-bde`)
2. Different combinations of output streams, with and without newline...
3. Another script command for the processbuilder like `"cmd.exe", "/k", "manage-bde.exe", "-unlock", "D:", "-password",` or with `/c` instead of `/k`
4. With and without admin rights
5. Simple *.bat with the command `manage-bde.exe -unlock D: -password` (which works perfectly)
6. Locking the drive through a java command (which works perfectly)
7. The command without `-password` (which let's bitlocker claim that I have to define how I want to unlock the drive)

I googled around for some time and found others having this problems but in a different way with other applications. So it seems like a very common error message.

**My guess**

I think it has something to do with how I handle my Java output as Bitlocker input. Maybe I am using the wrong streams to write to.

I can't provide the value of the password within the script variable, because Bitlocker want doesn't accept that way of entering the password. Usually you enter `manage-bde -unlock D: -password` within the command line and after a few lines of output Bitlocker asks you for the password.

Well I described it as good as I can and hope that someone knows what the problem is.

Any suggestion, even if it just leads to a more precise error message, would be appreciated. If you have any questions, just let me know!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did Not manage to get this working so I Build a workaround

Answer (score 1):

I encountered same problem recently. I did a lot search. It seems that mange-bde.exe doesn't read user input from stdin. Someone said ssh client and telent clent running on Linux doesn't read password from stdin. Another example Linux command passwd. It has a flag called -stdin which enable the shell to read password from stdin. Therefore, I guessed manage-bde.exe may works in a similar way.

My solution is simulating keyboard input. The awt package can do the job.